# Is every boundary point of a set a limit point of that set

Tags: general-topology

Is every boundary point of a set a limit point of that set?
Do not just focou on a metric space.

Comment: I find that for {(x,y)|x^2+y^2=0或x^2+y^2≥1} (0,0) is a boundary point but not a limit point.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What can be said about boundary points and limitpoints of a singleton in $\mathbb R$ equipped with its usual topology?

Comment: so you mean that's not true?

Comment: I find that for {(x,y)|x^2+y^2=0或x^2+y^2≥1} (0,0) is a boundary point but not a limit point.

Comment: Many thanks to you. It's my first time to learn this and I'm cofused with these conceptions.

Comment: You are correct in saying that $(0,0)$ is a boundary point of that set, and not a limitpoint. Likewise $a\in\mathbb R$ is a boundary point of $\{a\}$ but is not a limit point of $\{a\}$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Since ${\rm Bd}(A)=\bar{A}\cap\overline{(X-A)}$, so if 
for example that $A=\{x\}\subset {\sf R}^2$, the statement fails.